# sending form data onto backend

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I have build a form in react using material ui and the form data is to be sent onto the backend. For checking purpose I am checking whether the fields are displaying the data properly therefore, all the fields are showing the values but the dateAndTime field is not connected with rest of the fields so, how can I connect it with rest of the fields so that it can be sent with rest of the fields?

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import Link from "@mui/material/Link";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { TextareaAutosize } from "@mui/material";
import DateTimePicker from "@mui/lab/DateTimePicker";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Select, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
// import { Fab } from "@mui/material";
// import {AddIcon} from '@material-ui/icons';
const theme = createTheme();

export default function CampaignDesignForm() {
  
  const [dateAndTime, setDateAndTime] = React.useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    campaignName: "",
    campaignDescription: "",
    // dateAndTime,
    campaignDuration: "",
    characterSize: "",
    characterSelection: "",
    characterDamage: "",
  });
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const handle = (e) => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    newData[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setData(newData);
    console.log(newData);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 2,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Box
            component="form"
            noValidate
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            sx={{ mt: 3 }}
          >
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography
                  component="h1"
                  variant="h5"
                  style={{
                    background: "#c9c3c3",
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    marginBottom: "20px",
                  }}
                >
                  Add New Campaign
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  autoComplete="campaignName"
                  name="campaignName"
                  value={data.campaignName}
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="firstName"
                  label="Campaign Name"
                  autoFocus
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    handle(e);
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextareaAutosize
                  aria-label="minimum height"
                  minRows={5}
                  placeholder="Campaign Description"
                  style={{ width: 400 }}
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="campaignDescription"
                  //   label="Campaign Description"
                  name="campaignDescription"
                  value={data.campaignDescription}
                  autoComplete="campaignDescription"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    handle(e);
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                  <DateTimePicker
                    renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
                    label="Campaign Date & Time"
                    value={dateAndTime}
                    name="campaignDateAndTime"
                    // onChange={(e) => {
                    //   handle(e);
                    // }}
                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                      setDateAndTime(newValue);
                    }}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="campaignDuration"
                  value={data.campaignDuration}
                  label="Campaign Duration in Days"
                  type="number"
                  id="campaignDuration"
                  autoComplete="campaignDuration"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    handle(e);
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
                    Character Size
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    name="characterSize"
                    // value={characterSize}
                    label="Character Size"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      handle(e);
                    }}
                    // onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value={110}>110%</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={125}>125%</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={150}>150%</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={200}>200%</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
                    Character Selection
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    name="characterSelection"
                    // value={characterSelection}
                    label="Character Selection"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      handle(e);
                    }}
                    // onChange={(e)=>{setCharacterSelection(e)}}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value="Character 1">Character 1</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Character 2">Character 2</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Character 3">Character 3</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="characterDamage"
                  label="Character Damage"
                  type="number"
                  id="characterDamage"
                  value={data.characterDamage}
                  autoComplete="characterDamage"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    handle(e);
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                marginTop: "20px",
                marginBottom: "30px",
              }}
            >
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                style={{ display: "block", width: "90px", marginLeft: "200px" }}
              >
                Save
              </Button>
              <Button variant="contained">Update</Button>
            </div>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the other fields, you can include that in your `data` object:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    campaignName: "",
    campaignDescription: "",
    dateAndTime: "",
    campaignDuration: "",
    characterSize: "",
    characterSelection: "",
    characterDamage: "",
  });
```

And when changing, instead of calling `setDateAndTime` you can change the data object as needed:

```
   onChange={(newValue) => {
      setData(d => ({...d, dateAndTime: newValue}));
   }}
```

Lastly, don't forget to bind your value to your `data.dateAndTime` instead of `dateAndTime`:

```
value={data.dateAndTime}
```

Comment: Which console you are referring to? The one inside the handle won't get called since we don't call that function. Even if it did, `setState` is asnychronous, you will get the updated state variables inside a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I got it thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Hi unless of saving the date value in his separate state value you can add it as property in your state 'data'

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <DateTimePicker
                renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
                label="Campaign Date & Time"
                value={data.dateAndTime}
                name="campaignDateAndTime"
                // onChange={(e) => {
                //   handle(e);
                // }}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  setData((data) => {
                    return {
                    ...data,
                    dateAndTime: newValue
                    }
                  });
                }}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </Grid>
```

and you will delete the separate dateAndTime state

Comment: please put a console.log(newValue)  in the firstLine of the onChange() on DateTimePicker and see if you're getting the date there